# System.BadImageFormatException error when loading Visual Studio Express

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

When I try to load Visual Studio Express 2010, I get the following error at the VS splash screen and then the program fails to load.

System.BadImageFormatException

I've looked around for causes for this error, but most of what I've found is related to people getting this error with their own code or Windows services.  Why am I getting this error while trying to load Visual Studio?  How can I go about fixing it?